# Can the ASP.NET Core hosting bundle 5 run .NET/ASP.NET Core 2.1 applications as well?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-5.0

Can the ASP.NET Core hosting bundle 5 run .NET/ASP.NET Core 2.1 applications as well?

If not, is it possible to install the v2.1 hosting bundle in parallel to the v5 hosting bundle?

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Core runtimes can be installed side-by-side. In addition, newer versions of the .NET Core SDK are usually able to build applications that target previous versions of the runtime in a compatible manner. Generally, you only need the latest runtimes required by the application SDK and the latest patch version (generally, you should only need to install the latest SDK/runtime). Over time, when you install the .NET Core runtime and the updated version of the SDK, you may want to download from your computer Remove the outdated version of .NET Core from. Deleting the old version of the runtime may change the runtime that chooses to run the shared framework application.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?tabs=windows

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew that. I'm talking about the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle and its capabilities to communicate between the application and the IIS.

Comment: Is this helpful to you：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/176303/net-core-31-apps-with-the-net-5-hosting-bundle-are.html